# What does the word "going" mean in the following context? It's from an architecture book.

Tags: meaning

The height of each stepping should not be less than 100mm nor exceed 190mm. The **going**  of each stepping should not be less than 250mm.

Answer (score 2):

The *going* of a step in a staircase is the horizontal distance a person moves while traversing a step.  It's measured from the step's nosing to the nosing of the next step.  The nosing is the portion of the step that extends beyond the riser.  If there's no nosing, then the going is just the tread depth.  Go [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stairs) for a discussion of staircase construction.

Answer (score 0):

It's the depth of each step of a flight of stairs, as distinct from the height or *rise*.  See, for instance, [Pear Stairs](https://www.pearstairs.co.uk/staircase-buillding-regulations)

Comment: This isn't strictly true. The horizontal depth of a step would be from nosing to the next riser. If there's an overlapping nosing (there often is), the *going* would be slightly less than this.